# Count pageloads with asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to count pageloads but I keep getting this error message on the browser:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
MoveNext in LoadPage.cshtml, line 4

Any ideas why message1 is null?

My controller code:

```
public IActionResult LoadPage()
    {


        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult LoadPage(Message message)
    {
        Message message1 = new Message();
        message1.Text = "Pageloads: ";
        message1.Number += 1;

        return View("LoadPage", message);
    }
```

And my view:

```
<form asp-controller="MyForms" asp-action="LoadPage" method="post">
<p>@Model.Text @Model.Number</p> 
<input id="btnLoad" type="submit" value="Click here to load page" />
</form>
```

Comment: You're creating a `message1` variable, but just returning the `message` parameter as it instead. It's a very likely cause of error.

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas why message1 is null?

It is not null. Most likely `message` is null since you are getting it in the controller and passing it to your view.

```
return View("LoadPage", message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view is using the code `Model.Number`, that means you need to pass a non null object of Message class. You can do that in your GET action method.

```
public IActionResult LoadPage()
{
   var vm = new Message();
   return View(vm);
}
```

Also you don't need to recreate a new Message object, you can use the one used as the method parameter. You also need to clear the model state dictionary to see the updated value. You can use the `ModelState.Clear()` method to do so.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoadPage(Message message)
{     
    message.Text = "Pageloads: ";
    message.Number += 1;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View("LoadPage", message);
}
```

Comment: If used the ModelState.Clear() approach, it should modify `message` not `message1`.

Comment: Yea ! Copy paste mistake ! Thanks for pointing out. Fixed now.